# How do you match a pattern skipping exceptions?

Tags: regex, vim

In `vim`, I'd like to match a regular expression in a search and replace operation, but with exceptions — a list of matches that I want to skip.

For example, suppose I have the text:

> -one- lorem ipsum -two- blah blah -three- now is the time -four- the quick brown -five- etc. etc.

(but with lots of other possibilities) and I want to match `-\(\w\+\)-` and replace it with `*\1*` but skipping over (not matching) `-two-` and `-four-`, so the result would be:

> *one* lorem ipsum -two- blah blah *three* now is the time -four- the quick brown *five* etc. etc.

It seems like I should be able to use some kind of assertion (lookbehind, lookahead, something) for this, but I'm coming up blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a *negative lookahead* assertion. In Vim, that's done via [`:help /\@!`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21), like `(?!pattern)` in Perl.

Basically, you say *don't match `FOO` here, and in general match word characters*:

```
/-\(\%(FOO\)\@!\w\+\)-/
```

Note how I'm using *non-capturing groups* ([`:help /\%(`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25%28)). What's still missing is an assertion on the end, so the above would also exclude `-FOOBAR-`. As we have a unique end delimiter here, it's easiest to append that:

```
/-\(\%(FOO-\)\@!\w\+\)-/
```

Applied to your example, you just need to introduce two branches (for the two exclusions) in place of `FOO`, and you're done:

```
/-\(\%(two-\|four-\)\@!\w\+\)-/
```

Or, by factoring out the duplicated end delimiter:

```
/-\(\%(\%(two\|four\)-\)\@!\w\+\)-/
```

This matches any word characters in between dashes, *except* if those words form either `two` or `four`.

Comment: Ah, perfect. I just wasn't getting how to do that in the middle of the expression for some reason. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The *negative lookahead* in my other answer is the direct solution, but its syntax is a bit complex (and there can be patterns where the rules for the delimiter are not so simple, and the result then is much less readable).

As you're using substitution, an **alternative** is to put the selection logic into the *replacement* part of `:substitute`. Vim allows a Vimscript expression in there via [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression).

We have the captured word in `submatch(1)` (equivalent to `\1` in a normal replacement), and now just need to check for the two excluded words; if it's one of those, do a no-op substitution by returning the original full match (`submatch(0)`), else just return the captured group.

```
:substitute/-\(\w\+\)-/\=submatch(index(['two', 'four'], submatch(1)) == -1 ? 1 : 0)/g
```

It's not shorter than the lookahead pattern (well, we could *golf* the pattern and drop the ternary operator, as a boolean is represented by `0`/`1`, anyway), so here I would still use the pattern. But in general, it's good to know that there's more than one way to do it :-)